# Displaying the difference between rows in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named `Employee_audit` with following schema,

| emp_audit_id | eid | name | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Daniel | 1000 |
| 2 | 1 | Dani | 1000 |
| 3 | 1 | Danny | 3000 |

My goal is to write a SQL query which will return in following format, considering the first row also as changed value from null.

| columnName | oldValue | newValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | null | Daniel |
| salary | null | 1000 |
| name | Daniel | Dani |
| name | Dani | Danny |
| salary | 1000 | 3000 |

I have written the below SQL query,

```
WITH cte  AS 
(
  SELECT empid,
         name,
         salary, 
         rn=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY emp_audit_id)
  FROM   Employee_audit 
) 
SELECT oldname=CASE WHEN c1.Name=c2.Name THEN '' ELSE C1.Name END,
       newname=CASE WHEN c1.Name=c2.Name THEN '' ELSE C2.Name END,
       oldsalary=CASE WHEN c1.salary=c2.salary THEN NULL ELSE C1.salary END,
       newsalary=CASE WHEN c1.salary=c2.salary THEN NULL ELSE C2.salary END
FROM cte c1 INNER JOIN cte c2 
ON c1.empid=c2.empid AND c2.RN=c1.RN + 1
```

But it gives the result in following format

| oldname | newname | oldsalary | newsalary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Daniel | Dani | null | null |
| Dani | Danny | 1000 | 3000 |

Could you please answer me, how can I get the required result.

Comment: You've tagged 2 different databases mysql and sql-server. Are you sure you need the solution for both of them?

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS of interest... not multiple. And if you present your sample data as DDL+DML it makes it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Which database? `ROW_NUMBER()` won't give you the previous or next value in a set, that's what `LEAD()` or `LAG()` would do. All of those functions were added to MySQL 8, so you're either asking for SQL Server, or *specifically* for MySQL 8

Comment: I am seeking answer for SQL server

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() works in SQL server as well

Comment: SQL Server has change tracking since 2005 and temporal tables since 2016, essentially in all supported versions. You can create a far better solution than `Employee_audit`. As for the `format` you want, there's no way to identify which change refers to which row (Primary Key).

Comment: @Techie321 all analytic and windowing functions are available in SQL Server. It's MySQL that didn't have any until recently. And the results you want are unusable due to the lack of a PK value. I suspect those aren't the *exact* results you want.

Comment: @Techie321 you **want** the SQL and T-SQL tags, they are really what the question is about. SQL Server is just the RDBMS, but T-SQL is what you are writing the query in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give each row a row number in a CTE then join on yourself to the next row you can compare the old and the new values. Unioning the 2 different column names is a bit clunky however, if you needed a more robust solution you might look at pivoting the data.

You also obviously have to convert all values to a common datatype e.g. a string.

```
declare @Test table (emp_audit_id int, eid int, [name] varchar(32), salary money);

insert into @Test (emp_audit_id, eid, [name], salary)
values
(1, 1, 'Daniel', 1000),
(2, 1, 'Dani', 1000),
(3, 1, 'Danny', 3000);

with cte as (
    select emp_audit_id, eid, [name], salary
      , row_number() over (partition by eid order by emp_audit_id) rn
    from @Test
)
select C.emp_audit_id, 'name' columnName, P.[Name] oldValue, C.[name] newValue
from cte C
left join cte P on P.eid = C.eid and P.rn + 1 = C.rn
where coalesce(C.[name],'') != coalesce(P.[Name],'')
union all
select C.emp_audit_id, 'salary' columnName, convert(varchar(21),P.salary), convert(varchar(21),C.salary)
from cte C
left join cte P on P.eid = C.eid and P.rn + 1 = C.rn
where coalesce(C.salary,0) != coalesce(P.salary,0)
order by C.emp_audit_id, columnName;
```

Returns:

| emp_audit_id | columnName | oldValue | newValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name | NULL | Daniel |
| 1 | salary | NULL | 1000.00 |
| 2 | name | Daniel | Dani |
| 3 | name | Dani | Danny |
| 3 | salary | 1000.00 | 3000.00 |

I highly encourage you to add DDL+DML (as show above) to all your future questions as it makes it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Thank You Dale, It is working perfectly fine. :)

Comment: @Techie321 no worries - the other solution works perfectly as well - just so you know and have choice on technnique.

Comment: Dale ,how can we make this in a single select query, because  let's say for 10 fields, 10 select query and union all making the query slow.

Comment: Techie321 I knew you would ask this, and you need to ask a new question this time ensuring it accurately reflects your problem. The suggestions made by @PanagiotisKanavos in the comments will be a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

The lead and lag functions are to help you out.

The "diffs" calculates differences for each column you need to find diff to

```
with diffs as (
    select 'name' colName, emp_audit_id, eid, lag(name, 1, null) over (partition by eid order by emp_audit_id) oldValue, name newValue
    from some_table
    union all
    select 'salary', emp_audit_id, eid, cast(lag(salary, 1, null) over (partition by eid order by emp_audit_id) as varchar), cast(salary as varchar) newValue
    from some_table
)
select * 
from diffs 
where oldValue <> newValue or oldValue is null 
order by emp_audit_id, eid
```

Comment: There's no need for UNION and two scans to get the differences. A single scan with multiple `CASE WHEN` or `IIF` for the field name and changes can produce the same result

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos That's an interesting point - post your answer and let the best solution (from the OP point ov view) win! (:

Comment: Thank you @ekochergin. Which is more efficient this answer or Dale's Solution?

Comment: It will be so ugly that even if it works .... To get multiple results per row, `CROSS APPLY` with rows would work. But the SELECT would need one `case` for each attribute field *and* one big `case` to determine the field name.

Comment: @Techie321 it is only up to you to find it out. Run both of solutions against your database having real data and compare outputs and characteristics (IOs, CPU time and the execution time).
The solution suggested by PanagiotisKanavos may be the better way here.

Comment: Hey @PanagiotisKanavos! I really think you need to post your idea as a separate answer

Comment: @Techie321 try them. Put both in the same SSMS window, put `SHOW STATISTICS IO ON` att the toop and execute them with the `Show Actual Execution plan` option. The execution plans will show you the cost, the IO statistics (in the messages) will show you the IO impact.

Comment: According the execution plans, with this trivial amount of data, this solution is faster 34% vs 58% :) (8% setup). Which is best is also down to which you understand... its certainly easier to maintain a query where you can follow the logic.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, btw thanks for adding "with" to my answer. What do you mean by "faster 34% vs 58%"? I'd understand "faster by 34%" or sort of that, but "faster % vs %" is not clear to me. (I'm not a native speaker as you might have notice)

Comment: If you turn on execution plan display in SSMS it shows the percentage of time taken for each query that is run. So in my window 8% to setup the tables and data, 58% to run my query and 34% to run your query (I have them both in the same window). Its pretty rough and ready and not very accurate (use statistics for that) but gives an idea of which of 2 solutions performs better.

Comment: In my system ekochergin's solution was efficient with query cost 80% compare to Dale's solution with query cost 87%.  I will try to analyze Panagiotis Kanavos's point as well to make it more efficient. Thank you everyone :)